# Search all pages for a <body> with unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to search all web pages you developed (not just current page the user is on) for a body tag with a specified ID? If so how would I go about doing this in Javascript? Also, how would I go about re-directing the user to the page that contains that body with the unique ID?

Comment: You cannot do this with javascript, since its scope is limited to the page which it is running in. If you are using a mvc style application, however, you can redirect to page/specificPageId (or something like that) quite easily. `window.location.href= newUrlHere` (Obviously for this you would have to have a specific page naming scheme which your code is aware of)

Comment: Thanks, I do have a specific page naming scheme so this should be a good solution. However, is it possible to search for webpage that contains a specific keyword in its name?

Comment: Why are you even trying to go by body ids and not urls? E.g., if you have a page with body id "123" why not call that page "mypage123.htm" (or .php, .asp, .jsp, whatever). The only reason I can think of to even give a body an id is if you have a stylesheet shared between pages and want to apply specific styles to one page's body.

Comment: The issue is this isn't the only redirection I'm planning to do and this script will be quite general, so I'm wondering if I can identify a webpage by only knowing part of its name? Say can I located xxx_page1.html by only searching for 'page1'?

Comment: It will be easier if you name the html file with the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it, you could do it if you knew the pages' urls:

(using jQuery)

```
function searchPages(urls,elem,success,failure){
    nextUrl(urls,0);
    // this calls itself as a callback because $.load is asynchronous
    function nextUrl(i){ // this function tries to load a body#myId for the url 
         $('<div /'>).load(urls[i]+' '+elem,function(){ 
             // if it loaded there'd be html
             if($(this).html()!=='') success.call(this,urls[i]); 
             // if you've loaded all the pages, then you're done
             if(i===urls.length) 
                failure.call(this,urls[i]);
             // otherwise, call the function again for the next url
             else nextUrl(i+1);
           });
    };
}

searchPages(['/url1','/url2','/url3'],'body#myId',function(url){
   console.log(url); // this is the url you want
   console.log($(this)); // $(this) is the div that the body elem was loaded into
},failed);

// this is called if you don't find the page
function failed(){ alert('no page found'); };
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to exactly how this code is working? If you do, I'll +1.

Comment: +1. Clever work-around. I don't really think this is going to be a usable solution though, since `.load()` will strip away the stylesheets, external scripts, and `head` from the source...

Comment: @nbrooks the idea at the end is to get the `body`'s `ID`, isn't it? +1 too

Comment: @jfk I think the idea the OP was going for was a literal redirect, showing the new page (fully styled, etc.), updating the url and such -- based on an already given id. But that's just a theory. :)

Comment: @nbrooks you are right ... I guess your comment made bokonic to improve the answer and pass the ID as parameter so you can redirect to the url that matches the index.